# DMD version for Mac 10.5.8

Tags: d, dmd

Could someone please tell me which version of DMD to install on Mac 10.5.8?
I can't find a minimum-system-requirements document anywhere.

Thanks.

Comment: Version: 2.069.2 (latest) doesn't work. Says - 10.6 is required.

Comment: Don't you receive updates from Apple anymore ? Thought Apple has kinda long time support for all products ?